# Trying to email a PDF of a single Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to email a PDF of a single Google Sheet and have compiled the below so far.  However, the recipient receives a PDF file that fails to load or even preview in Gmail.

```
function sendEmail(){  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  const url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId();

  const opt = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  };
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, opt);
  const blob = response.getBlob().setName('Sheet1.pdf');

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'email@address.com',
    subject: 'subject',
    htmlBody: 'body',
    attachments: blob
  });
}
```

Comment: It works for me, try a different content of the sheet, probably some weird character causes it to conflict.

Comment: use this: `var url_base = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()+'/';`

Comment: @Marios -- Thanks, that worked!